# Warning when I add uses-permission on my manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

When I add the code:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I get the warning on the `uses-sdk line`

> Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes
>   apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the
>   android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details.

Why is that so and how do I resolve this?

Full code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.johnsmithz.appone"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.johnsmithz.appone.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you post your full android manifest file, please. thanks :)

Comment: Post your uses-sdk line

Comment: set your latest sdk version at this line `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` in manifest.

Comment: `android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

Comment: hm indeed on 19 it disappeared o.O but why D:

Comment: Because 19 is the latest SDK version ;)

Comment: I believe it's because android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was not introduced until KitKat. Prior to that, permission was not necessary to merely _read_ from external storage.